Matplotlib issue with mosaic and colorbars
I am facing a strange behaviour with my code.
I don't understand why the subplot at the top left has a different space between the imshow and the colorbar compared to the subplot at the top right.
And also I don't understand why the colorbar at the bottom is not aligned with the one at the top right.
Can you explain this ?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.rand(100, 100)

mosaic = "AB;CC"
    
fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained")
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic(mosaic)

img = ax_dict['A'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['A'])

img = ax_dict['B'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['B'])

img = ax_dict['C'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['C'])

plt.show()



I posted this issue on Matplotlib github page and get an answer from jklymak.
This is not the most elegant way to do it, but it works. However, if you want to place the colorbar at the bottom you have to adapt the code, updating the value in the inset_axes and also the orientation of the colorbar.
img = ax['A'].imshow(matrix, aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(img, cax=ax['A'].inset_axes([1.02, 0, 0.05, 1]))
img = ax['B'].imshow(matrix, aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(img, cax=ax['B'].inset_axes([1.02, 0, 0.05, 1]))
img = ax['C'].imshow(matrix, aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(img, cax=ax['C'].inset_axes([1.02, 0, 0.05, 1]))


I don't know the actual answer, but you can make a workaround by messing with the padding. This produces something sort of reasonable. I hate messing with values like this though. You can check out other manual placement options in this example.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.rand(100, 100)

mosaic = "AB;CC"
    
fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained")
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic(mosaic)

img = ax_dict['A'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['A'], pad=-0.08)

img = ax_dict['B'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['B'], pad=0.04)

img = ax_dict['C'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['C'], pad=0.02)

plt.show()


Edit
If you remove the constrained layout and use tight_layout you get better alignment of the top plots, but now the bottom row doesn't take up the full width
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.rand(100, 100)

mosaic = "AB;CC"
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic(mosaic)

img = ax_dict['A'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['A'])

img = ax_dict['B'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['B'])

img = ax_dict['C'].imshow(matrix, aspect="auto")
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax_dict['C'])

fig.tight_layout()



Thank you very much for your feedback. However it seems like it's a manual process which is not very convenient. I would like to find something automatic.

Agreed. I don't know offhand why that's happening

@Mo0nKizz I added another example. Seems like constrained is part of the issue
